# Instantiate a class with internal ctor, from a different assembly

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I thought an `internal` ctor cannot be accessed from a different assembly. Today for the first time I actually needed to use this idea, but it doesn't work as I expected - it can be accessed from a different assembly.

```
namespace A {

  public class AA {
    internal AA() { }
  }

}

namespace TestNamespace {

  public class TestClass {

    public void TestMethod() {
      var instance = new A.AA();     // <-- this compiles!
    }

  }

}
```

...so I'm doing it wrong, or don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: `Assembly` != `Namespace`. These namespaces are probably exists within the same assembly, see my answer for more details.

Comment: Make sure you are not using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to make internals visible to your test application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Assembly != Namespace`

> Namespaces provide a logical organizational system. Namespaces are
>   used both as an "internal" organization system for a program, and as
>   an "external" organization system — a way of presenting program
>   elements that are exposed to other programs.

While

> Assemblies are used for
>   physical packaging and deployment. An assembly may contain types, the
>   executable code used to implement these types, and references to other
>   assemblies.

Assemblies are usually projects, `C#` wise.

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664631%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: HAHA! Yes of course. I was busy testing and had both the classes in the same assembly. So many windows open, things get messy...

Comment: Might help someone else though, it was driving me mad... Like someone told me 1+1!=2 even though I know it does.